# Can some one explain IResolver<T> internal interface in asp.net MVC 3?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

The code in its derivatives MultiServiceResolver and SingleServiceResolver are highly compact and can somebody explain what they are doing or their purposes are and the role played by them in dependency resolution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're the ones responsible of going to the DependencyResolver and ask it to resolve the types they asks for (i/e IViewEngine or IControllerFactory).

more info about the DependencyResolver can be found here:
http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/service-location-pt5-idependencyresolver.html

Basically SingleServiceResolver calls GetSingleService from the dependencyResolver, and MultiServiceResolver calls GetServices. You can set your own DependencyResolver to use your own IOC container (AutoFac/Ninject/StructureMap etc.) using the SetResolver method in the DependencyResolver static class. by default (If you don't override it) the resolver doesn't resolve any types.

Basically this decouples the implementations of some types (i/e ViewEngines/Collection or ValueProviderFactories/ValueProviderFactoryCollections) that use the ServiceLocator pattern in the ASP.NET MVC pipeline from the ASP.NET MVC implementation and the DependencyResolver static class.

Answer (score 1):

Recently, I've created a blog post that a little explains MultiServiceResolver and SingleServiceResolver.

http://www.beletsky.net/2011/08/inside-aspnet-mvc-iresolver-and-its.html